# php.ini vs configuration at runtime

Tags: php, apache

Considering a common LAMP setup, you can leave your PHP configurations at some `.ini` file to PHP read and apply them upon web server initialization. But how does it compare, in performance matters, to runtime configurations that developers usually leave at the application bootstrap file?!

Since PHP uses a [shared nothing architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_nothing_architecture) , each request will starts a new (sub?)process so it will need to read the `*.ini` files again? Or it  comes already shared by the main PHP process? If yes, changing a lot of configurations at runtime will add much more overhead to each request than leaving that at `ini` files, right?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, firstly it is not PHP that forks a new process. That is completely up to the Web server that PHP is a apart of. So yes, if you are using LAMP, and therefor Apache, the entirety of the PHP module has to get loaded into memory for each process anyways (each process is upwards of 30-50 MB which is massive!). 
And again yes, it will need to read the `.ini` for each new process, but that is completely negligible to all of the other loading that needs to be done.

Ofcourse, the alternative is to use `ini_set` which would have to be called on each request. Performance wise, it would be just the same as an `.ini` file **IF** processes were recreated for every request. However, processes are oftentimes reused (which is why you should tinker with the min and max process count for the Apache config).

So in conclusion, there is a slight performance benefit for a php.ini file.

However, like all performance concerns with PHP and Apache, do what WORKS! If you are trying to optimize, it's probably your queries!

Comment: Nowadays performance questions are more about knowing how stuff works under the hood than getting better profiling results. Thanks for sharing these details :)